# Multiple buttons with onclick animations - certain ones not finishing setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have three buttons with different onclick animations. On click, it adds the "active" class to start the CSS animation. And with setTimeout, it removes that class to remove the final state of the animation and so the button can be clicked again.

Unfortunately though, when you're quickly clicking on the buttons, certain buttons doesn't go through the setTimeout.

Not sure exactly what's going on but here's my js.

```
var i=0;
$('button').each(function(){
    i++;
    $('.btn-' + i).on('click', toggleBtn);

    function toggleBtn() {
      btn = this;
      // btn = btn.querySelector(".btn-" + i);
      btn.classList.add('active');

       setTimeout(function () {
          btn.classList.remove('active');
      }, 3000)

    }
});
```

Here's the codepen as well.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqJxZd

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each time you click a different button, you lose the setTimeout reference.

one solution is to put the setTimeout in an external function, like this:

```
function stOut(btn) {
setTimeout(function () {
    btn.classList.remove('active');
}, 3000)
```

}

and calls the function toggleBtn within its function stOut(btn) and passing btn as parameter

Comment: Thanks, Henrique! I updated the code in codepen and looks like it's working correctly now. Appreciate it!